# Долго отрабатывает запрос по timestamp в postgres (версия 14)

Tags: sql, postgresql, запрос, select, timestamp

Запрос при фильтрации по полю timestamp выполняется за секунду, если дату передавать в виде строки. Если дату передавать в виде timestamp, то запрос выполняется более 30 минут. В чем может быть причина?

Пример условия с длительной выборкой:

```
    and dta.date_time >= to_timestamp('01.02.2023','dd.mm.yyyy')
    and dta.date_time < to_timestamp('01.03.2023','dd.mm.yyyy')
```

Пример условия с быстрой выборкой:

```
    and dta.date_time >= '2023-02-01'
    and dta.date_time < '2023-03-01'
```

Тип поля date_time timestamptz. Добавление временной зоны в условие так же не помогает.

Comment: План запроса смотрели? Как построен индекс по полю и есть ли он вообще?

Comment: Беглое гугление по фразе "postgresql slow query by timestamp" даёт тучу ответов. Проблема видимо в том, что `timestamp` нужно ещё пересчитывать в конкретный момент времени, учитывая таймзону сервера. Судя по тому, что там пишут, там вообще какой-то двойной или тройной пересчёт туда-сюда идёт между `timestamp` без зоны, с зоной, и чуть ли не в строку ещё и обратно. И какое-то из этих преобразований ещё и не даёт использовать индекс по этому полю.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло преобразование в timestamptz. Причем помогло именно вот такое преобразование: select '2023-01-01 00:00:00':: timestamptz

Comment: Оформите сами как ответ, может пригодится ещё кому.